# Keep getting an error in using sed command to append line after specific pattern in bash script file

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I have a `config.xml` file and a bash script file. I want to use the bash script to append a line to config.xml and save that result in config.xml.
For example, I want to append the line 'it never works' whenever there is the word 'Cordova' in `config.xml`. So I used:

```
sed '/Cordova/ a\ it never works' config.xml
```

and I get an error of "`sed: 1: "/Cordova/ a\ it never works": extra characters after \ at the end of a command`".

How do I fix this?

I'm using a Mac at the terminal command line.

Answer (score 2):

The version of `sed` on a Mac is the BSD variant, and it isn't as forgiving as the GNU `sed` version (alternatively, it hews more closely to the POSIX specification for [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and doesn't bend the rules as severely as GNU `sed` does).  In particular, commands such as `a` need the backslash at the end of a line, and the remaining material on the next line:

```
sed '/Cordova/ a\
it always works like this, even with GNU sed' config.xml
```

With multiple lines to add, all except the last end with the backslash.

```
sed '/Cordova/ a\
it always works like this\
even with GNU sed' config.xml
```

Note that both these do not add a newline after the appended material.  For that, you need:

```
sed '/Cordova/ a\
    it always works like this, even with GNU sed
    ' config.xml
```

Note too that `sed` eliminates the leading blanks from the appended material.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk for clarity, robustness, portability, efficiency and most other desirable qualities of software:

```
awk '{print} /Cordova/{print "it ALWAYS works"}' config.xml
```